# How to remove the greyed out look of a disbled UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I've got a UIButton that i want to look exactly the same when it's in its disabled state as when it's in its Normal state.  Right now it has a slight greyed out look to it.

Comment: So how will users know it's disabled if it looks like it can function normally?

Comment: The enabled state has a background image that will say "click to continue" or something to that effect.  When the button isn't clickable it won't have any message like that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do not use enabled property or setEnabled:NO method, instead use:

```
[myButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

That would prevent the button for being touched, but without changing his looks!

The other way is if your button is a custom button and has an image:

```
[button setImage:someImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:someImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[button setEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: This will do what the OP wants, but as BoltClock said, it might be a confusing to disable a button without letting the user know that it is disabled.

Comment: I Agree, but sometimes you deal with some kind of clients that will get what they want one way or another, is not always up to de dev...

Comment: Sometimes for me always) you just have to tell the client "No" to their bad ideas.

Comment: Thanks, The first approach works. I agree with Rickay but in my situation I want the background image to be fully visible in all situations.