# Disable UIButton from interaction without changing UIButton look (i.e. greyed out look)

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have the following code where my goal is to disable a `UIButton` from interaction once it is in the `selected` mode.

```
if (...){
    cell.requestButton.selected = YES;
    cell.requestButton.enabled = NO;
} else {
    cell.requestButton.selected = NO;
    cell.requestButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

The side-effect of disabling the UIButton is that it also changes the Button's appearance. Even if I set the same `UIImage` for both the button's both `selected` and `disabled` state, the appearance still takes on a greyed-out looked with a <1 alpha level. Is there a way that I could prevent the `disabled` state from changing the appearance of the UIButton at all?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to removed the greyed out look of a disbled UIButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626847/how-to-removed-the-greyed-out-look-of-a-disbled-uibutton)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the UIView's `userInteractionEnabled` property instead. Not sure if that works, but give it a try.
If that doesn't work, you could place a dummy UIView right over it, add constraints to use the original button's position and size, and have it enabled so that it swallows any taps.

Answer (score 1):

Either set the same style as the `UIControlStateNormal` to the `UIControlStateDisabled` or have a look at [`adjustsImageWhenDisabled`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/adjustsImageWhenDisabled).